# Error.RuntimeException: The exit status code '127' with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Im trying to use Snappy PDF for Laravel but when I try to download PDF file it returns an error on my macOS machine, but it works on windows machine. Please see more details below.

**Error**

> Error.RuntimeException: The exit status code '127' says something went wrong

I tried to install wkhtmltopdf using brew command but when I download pdf, it's ended up loading and not downloading the file.

**Brew command I used**

`brew cask install wkhtmltopdf`

I also tried to use `chmod` to give acces to the executable file but it is not giving the access.

**Command I tried to give access**

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

**This is the screenshot of files listed inside /usr/local/bin**

[image]

Comment: there is a installer for macos, [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Comment: @bhucho Already done that but nothing happens. I also tried to restart the app using `php artisan serve` but didn't work